# Which ComboBox event handler should I use?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have this problem with my code where I would like to display the change after the total amount is summed up and the user picks a banknote from the `ComboBox` but I'm not sure if I am using the correct event handler/trigger function and if I should do those conversions. The error I am getting is:

> Error 2   The event 'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=    J:\EDPtest1\EDPtest1\Form1.cs   100 49  EDPtest1

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Convert.ToDouble(comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged == total))
    {
        lblChange.Text = "Amount Correct";
    }
    else if (Convert.ToDouble(comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged > total))
    {
        lblChange.Text = "Total change: " + comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged - total;
    }
    else if(Convert.ToDouble(comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged < total))
    {
        lblChange.Text = "Please add more money";
    }
}
```

Comment: [ComboBox.SelectedItem Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work since it tells me that  the operators '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'objects' and 'double'

Comment: `(Convert.ToDouble(comboBox1.SelectedItem) == total)` <- Notice parens. Yours are in wrong place.

Comment: @CyanicWolf...You should cast second operand to double. See my updated answer.

Comment: i have added a different solution; you can check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`ComboBox.SelectedItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem(v=vs.110).aspx) **Property** instead of `SelectedIndexChanged` *event* in your `if` statements. And also based on your comment that you get this error:

> The operators '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'objects' and 'double'

You should cast second operand to `double`:

```
if (Convert.ToDouble(comboBox1.SelectedItem) == (double) total)
{
    lblChange.Text = "Amount Correct";
}
```

Comment: Ah yes thank you very much sir. This worked out just fine :) Just one last thing: when I try to subtract the total from the selected item it tells me that the Error 1 Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'double'

Comment: @CyanicWolf...Well you should convert to double your string value like this: `Double.Parse(yourstringvalue)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Convert.ToDouble(comboBox1.SelectedValue) == (total.ToDouble()))
{
    lblChange.Text = "Amount Correct";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`SelectedIndexChanged`  is an event you cannot compare that with a variable `total` assume that the variable is of type  `double` you what you need to do here is, You need to convert the SelectedText/SelectedValue to double and then do the comparison. Probably  `double.TryParse()` will be more suitable for converting string to double, than `Convert.ToDouble()`. I have included all these points in the snippet below:

```
double input;
if (double.TryParse(comboBox1.SelectedText, out input)) // can use comboBox1.SelectedValue also if you are binding the values
   {
     if (input == total)
     {
        lblChange.Text = "Amount Correct";
     }
     else if (input > total)
     {
        lblChange.Text = "Total change: " + (input - total);
     }
     else if (input < total)
     {
        lblChange.Text = "Please add more money";
     }
  }
  else
  {
       lblChange.Text = "Please add more money";
  }
```

Comment: Im still a beginner at coding but isn't it possible to avoid using another variable by using the code that S.Akbari provided me with? Thanks for the help though